# Long vs short wire when using DC

Tags: current, dc, wire

My knowledge of electricity is hobby level, maybe even less.

In a powersystem that runs entirely off Direct Current, powered by a 600 mAh lithion battery, imagine the following scenario:

```
+----[- Battery +]--- ~ 50cm ~ --- [ Light ] --- ~ 2m ~ --- [ Light ] ---+
|                                                                        |
+---------------------~ 5m ~ ------[ Light ] ---- ~ 10m ~ ---------------+
```

As DC loses power over distance, I wonder if the above diagram will make the intensity of the lights change keeping in mind that the battery is only just powerful enough to light all three lights.  Will one light be brighter than the other? The main reason here is that the length of the wires are difference.

Is there a minimum length in which the difference doesn't matter?
And if I increase the length of the wires bewteen the lights, will that make all lights equally bright without them becoming too dim?

What would be the best approach here? I wonder this so I can design around it. Although I can't go from DC to AC nor change the output of the battery, I have a bit of flexibility in the length of the wires.

Also, if I have just one light with 50 cm on one side and 5 m on the other side, can this damage the light and is the performance different than if I had it placed in the exact middle but the length of the wire is still 5.50 m?

Comment: What are the “lights”? LEDs? What kind? What’s the type of the battery? What gauge is your wire? Are the 3 lights really in series?

Comment: @jcaron the lights are normal old-skool lights, with small metal string that glows. They are all in series. The real setup will be different, but I need to understand how the length of the wire affect different components.

Comment: The RESISTANCE of the wire is depending on wire gauge (Area of the wire) together with the length and the metal in the wire. And by the way if it is AC or DC the voltage drop is there anyway! Use this https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html

Comment: And keep the question to one question, as it is now there are multiple questions !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Total wire resistance is all that matters. What length of is where matters not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your lights are really in series then they all receive the same current regardless of position along the wire. (This should make sense as where else can the current go if there are no parallel branches?)

With a constant voltage supply the resistance of the wire will cause some reduction in current. The lights have no way of knowing what the series resistance is and which side it's on. It could all be in one lump at a battery terminal, in the middle or spread evenly through the circuit.

Comment: Thanks. So all lights will be the same brightness then but the length of the wire may reduce the maximum throughput of the wire, am I understanding correctly? Does that also mean that it doesn't matter if there is 5cm wire on one end of a single light and 20m on the other end? vs putting the light in the middle of the wire?

Comment: You've understood correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know. :)

Answer (score 4):

### For *STEADY* DC, wire lengths need not be equal or together.

It's perfectly fine to do loop or unequal-length circuits like that *in steady-current DC*.  The wires throw [an electro-magnetic field](https://web.pa.msu.edu/courses/1997spring/PHY232/lectures/ampereslaw/wire.html#:%7E:text=Magnetic%20field%20of%20a%20wire&text=Magnetic%20fields%20arise%20from%20charges,that%20generates%20a%20magnetic%20field.), but if it's steady-current DC, this field acts like a refrigerator magnet - doesn't affect anything and nobody cares. Doesn't even bother animals.

As a counter-example, in AC power (or pulsed DC) we have a problem.  That magnetic field is now pulsing - not like a refrigerator magnet at all, but like the inside of an AC induction motor.  Those magnetic fields are now a huge problem, because they are inducing onto anything metallic (remember induction motor rotors are *aluminum*), generating eddy current heating on nearby objects, and vibration on the wires, resulting in metal fatigue and wire cracking.  (all that energy is bought and paid for by you, so it's even more wire losses and voltage drop).

So with AC or pulsed, the Code requirement is that opposite flow conductors must be kept together at all times [(photo 6 here)](https://iaeimagazine.org/2013/septemberoctober-2013/article-300-continued-electrical-inspections-for-the-combination-inspector/), or [special provisions must be made](https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/example-of-300-3-b-3.61833/) to keep anything metallic from being between them.  **If you plan to use PWM dimming, that is pulsed DC, and you must follow the "opposite conductors together" rule.** I hope you can avoid this; that will make your wires *even longer*.

### You have to do a *voltage drop* calculation on the wires.

There's no substitute for this.

**Especially in low voltage DC power**. Seriously. I see many youtubers attempt low voltage DC home power projects, and fail dismally.  *They never did a proper voltage drop calculation*, and used far-too-small wires.

### In a series circuit, add wire resistances.

And if this is all the same wire size, feel free to treat it as ONE wire of the sum-total length.  Say your circuit was wired with ALL the same wire size.  So I see 10m + 5m + 2m + 0.5m = 17.5m of wire length, so we can compute that as one 17.5m length of "whatever it is".

We can lookup the resistance of the wire in an engineering table.  For instance, 2.5mm<sup>2</sup> wire (slightly bigger than 14 AWG) is 7.41 milliohms per metre (often stated as 7.41 ohms per 1000m).

Now we multiply *"resistance per length"* by length.  Giving resistance obviously.    Example, we have 7.41 milliohm/m x 17.5 m --- giving 130 milliohms, or 0.130 ohms.

Next, we need to know the *current* moving on the wire. You didn't mention that current, so you'll need to find that out via measurement.

Armed with the current, we can plug into Ohms Law to see how the wire is dropping voltage behaving as a resistor:

```
 V = I x R
```

Or in the example case,

```
 V = I x 0.130
```

Let's say you are flowing 1.5 amps.  (I'm guessing).  In our example, voltage drop will be 1.5 x .13 = 0.195 volts. *That's not bad at all; even at 5V this is less than 5%.  However this is only an example*.

You will need to do your own calculation based on your own wire size and current.

### How to source bigger wire

Common electronics wire is very small (18 AWG or 0.75mm<sup>2</sup> or smaller), and I mentioned the common mistake.  If your calculations show you need *much* larger wire than you are accustomed to working with in low-voltage electronics, do not buy it from your electronics supplier - it'll be exotic (to them) and wildly overpriced.  Head straight over to the *electrical supply house* that supplies AC mains electricians.  They have larger sizes (like 6.0mm<sup>2</sup> or 10 AWG) *dirt cheap* - it's a commodity for them!

In fact if you need to get into REALLY big stuff, like those home-power projects I mentioned, consider using aluminum wire in sizes of 6 AWG or 10 mm<sup>2</sup> or larger.  It'll be 1/3 the price!

Comment: It should be noted that aluminium wire is only popular in the US for some reason.  Everywhere else that I’m aware of uses nothing but copper for domestic wiring.

Comment: @Frog - [Canada](https://www.canadianhomeinspection.com/home-reference-library/electrical/aluminum-wiring/) as well.

Comment: @Frog: I suspect it comes down to mains voltage. US and Canada use 120 V, most of the rest of the world uses 220–240 V. Doubling the voltage means you can deliver the same amount of power for the same distance with the same amount of power loss (and wire heating) using a wire with half the diameter (i.e. 1/4 the amount of metal). Thus, in a 240 V country, you're a lot less likely to end up needing those massive wire gauges for which switching to alumin(i)um wire makes sense — unless, of course, you're deliberately going off the grid and low voltage.

Comment: @ Ilmari Karonen - quite right, for 220-240 domestic installations the heaviest wire I’ve come across is 10sq mm, you’d probably go to 3-phase for any higher power requirements.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen US and Canada [are 240V countries](https://youtu.be/jMmUoZh3Hq4) and we jump to 240V *before* we jump to 30A. However, we are *really* 240V countries, like you're *really* a 400V/3-phase "wye" country.  Our 120V center-tap *precludes* 3-phase delivery, so we are forced to *ever larger* 240V feeders. Thomas Edison's fault. The minimum service offered today is 200A@240V split-phase, because the PoCo knows perfectly well you're gonna get a hot tub, tankless heater or electric car.  That would be equivalent to 65A @ 400V 3-phase "wye" aka Euro 230V. But 200A takes 84.9mm2 Cu wire!

Comment: @Frog We used it in *small appliance branch circuits* in the 1970s due to a copper shortage. *This went badly*, and taught us A LOT about using aluminum wire *correctly*. Everyone uses aluminum wire, *even Airbus*, **when the size warrants**... which is what my answer is saying.  As said above, "the size warrants" a lot more often in North American home wiring because of Edison's split-phase albatross.